# I can't make my armature affect any mesh deformation

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

I am having an impossible time setting my armature to auto-deform the mesh like I've seen a dozen times in YT tutorials. Every time I attempt to do so, I fail. Here is the workflow:

1. Select the mesh
2. Shift+Select the armature
3. Select Object - Parent - Armature Deform with Automatic Weights (Note: Ctrl + P does not show me any armature parenting options; I don't know why; seems to work for everyone else).

[Here is a link to my .blend file][1]. Just in case you are interested. I'm basically at my wit's end. I've recreated armatures for this stupid thing three times. Every single time, I watch someone in the tut very easily move their mesh around with Pose mode after they parent. But I can't. Ever.

If I need to use weight painting to do this manual, I will. But I would really like to know what I'm doing wrong since the manual way is going to add a lot of time. At this stage in my education, I'm still trying to understand all the basic functionality and this is one of those.

Comment: deparent the armature from the mesh, it's the mesh that is supposed to be parented to the armature. Also, before parenting, apply the scale and rotation of both armature and mesh. It looks like your problem has to do with the head bone, if you recreate one it will work fine, I don't know why. And your mesh is very high in polygons, do you need so many? Especially if you give it a Subdivision Surface (and 4 is a very high subdivision)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded your file and got it to work. I am very out of practice with Blender but the file seems to have issues. seems like a lot of vertices for the bear, there is some strangeness in scales of things too. there was a parent loop in the Teddy and armature , when I cleared the parenting the armature shrank. I ended up deleting the whole armature and just making a new one and then the parenting with automatic weights worked.

Comment: Thanks very much! It was simply that I parented in the wrong order.